# Radiobutton horizontal center alignment Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, grid, tkinter

I would like to arrange my Radiobuttons horizontally and centered on my Frame such as this example:

[image: After]

But I have only been able to do this:

[image: Before]

And this is my code :

```
 self.mit.grid(row=4, column=0)
 self.gpl2.grid(row=4, column=1)
 self.gpl3.grid(row=4, column=2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is a widget in the 0 column which is wider than the other widgets. Try setting a new frame as the parent of the group of radio buttons:

```
radiogroup = Frame(master)
# self.mit = Radiobutton(radiogroup, ...)
# ...
self.mit.grid(row=0, column=0)
self.gpl2.grid(row=0, column=1)
self.gpl3.grid(row=0, column=2)
radiogroup.grid(row=4, column=0)
```

Comment: Ops! Sorry, it was a typo :)

Comment: I haven't tested it, but it seems you have to set explicitly the `row` index, otherwise it is set in the next one. I have updated the code.